# HTTP GET Action Method with parameter of System.Type

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, system.type

I have the following action method

```
public PartialViewResult AddToBasket(int id, Type type)
{
    _basketService.AddToBasket(id, type);
    return UpdateBasket();
}
```

In one of my razor views I am rendering a link like this

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Add Box To Basket", "AddToBasket", "Basket", new {id = box.Id, type = typeof(BasketBox)}, new AjaxOptions {UpdateTargetId = "basket", OnSuccess = "showPopover();"}, new {})
```

This renders a link like this

```
http://localhost:37913/Public/Basket/AddToBasket/241415?type=MyProject.Shared.Repository.Models.BasketBox
```

However when `AddToBasket` is called, my type parameter is always null.

Is this even possible ?

Comment: A custom model binder could use a string to lookup the type and thus get the `Type` instance.

Comment: I'd suggest you really ought not to be exposing the implementation details of your *datatypes* as part of your publicly visible surface.